# How do I make a view expand like a Material "sheet"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a card-like view with elevation and a white background that I want to expand to fill up the whole screen. It's a card in a list (my own custom layout, not a `CardView`), and I want to make it take up the whole screen when it's tapped via a Fragment transition.

My first idea is to create a fake, identical view in the new fragment, place it at the item's position, and animate it to the top, while animating its layout bounds to take up the whole screen. However, I don't think this is the best idea, as Android will have to remeasure the layout every single frame while the animation is running (likely to lag). Is there a way I can get this effect in a clean way? I'm going to be using fragment transitions, so hopefully I can use `Animator` in some way, but I'll take any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the same, but instead of relayouting, do redrawing. Create custom implementation of view's onDraw(), it's not that hard.

View will fill entire screen but at the start of animation will draw only initial part.

Or you can just try your approach, it's easy to implement and may be it is not that slow.

Also, may be directly modifying view's setLeft(), setRight(), etc. with Animators is a valid solution.

Comment: Won't overriding `onDraw` not properly animate the shadow, though?

Comment: You are right, shadows will not be animated. Try Animators with animating left, righ, etc. properties of the view.